# Your password reset link has expired : Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to `reset password` from `forgot password` action using REST API:

```
http://domain/index.php/rest/V1/customers/password?
email=myemail@gmail.com&
template=email_reset&
websiteId=1
```

and I receive an email successfully to set new password as follow:

[image]

When click the button Set a New Password, I got this error

```
Your password reset link has expired
```

as follow :

[image]

when enter my email again in the last screen, I got another email to reset a new password as the first image, then click reset password and I can receive the proper screen and reset password function working fine as follow :

[image]

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all thanks @Shireen your comments help me to debug.
I have kind of similar issue and it resolved not in the best way.

@Jsparo30

when you request reset password link via API, Magento creates DirectLink(Link with the query string, has 2 params) which are as follows.

please check this file
`/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php`

[image]
and when you click the button on reset password email Magento try to access those query string params and get **Failed**[image]

due to they accessing the wrong param.

> to overcome this problem quickly all you need to just replace param
>   `token` with `amp;token`

**I know this is not the solution, but you can at least start with this.**

Comment: not working this

Answer (score 2):

The default admin password reset email template has an error, (at least it does in my case on 2.3.5 Commerce), should be `$user.user_id` instead of `$user.id`.

vendor\magento\module-user\view\adminhtml\email\password_reset_confirmation.html

Has:

`{{store url="admin/auth/resetpassword/" _query_id=$user.id _query_token=$user.rp_token _nosid=1}}`

Should be:

`{{store url="admin/auth/resetpassword/" _query_id=$user.user_id _query_token=$user.rp_token _nosid=1}}`

Easiest thing to do is copy this template into a new admin template (Marketing > Email Templates), make sure the user_id parameter is correct, and then assign it in Stores -> Configuration -> Admin -> Admin User Emails. Your password reset link should now have "id" and "token" query string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting some magento exception. To check what is that exception, go to class method

```
Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword::execute()
```

and in catch statement log the exception like die($exception);

Comment: Thanks, This is the exception I got. How can I fix ? Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException: Invalid value of "0" provided for the customerId field. in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:933 Stack trace: #0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(490): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->validateResetPasswordToken(0, '') #1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php(63)

Comment: If you want to change the password of the customer by which you are logged in then you can also use this api - http://domain/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me/password? or also try passing customer id in the api which you are currently using or may be you are using the wrong email id

Comment: where I can pass the customer id ?

Comment: Go to class  method Magento\Customer\ModelAccountManagement::\initiatePasswordReset and print_r($customer->getData()) after line# 513. Check if you are getting any data, if not then you are using an email id which does not exists in magento DB

Comment: This API  domain/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me/password? is using for update password and user is logged (he needs to just update). but I am talking about forgot password case. where I can pass the customer id as you mentioned in the second part of your answer. Thx.

Comment: I am still facing the problem. Invalid value of "0" provided for the customerId field. can you help ?

Comment: I have the same issue on M1, any update on this ?

Comment: Could anyone tell me how can i change reset link password from hours to minutes if possible with full path. As for same function there are multiple files

Comment: @Jsparo30 i am also getting this issues  " Invalid value of "0" provided for the customerId field"
did you find any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 1):

i recently encountered the similar issue :

> Your password reset link has expired

I tried to create programmatically an admin user and sent a forgot password email with this method :

```
$this->notificatorInterface->sendForgotPassword($admin)
```

This is how I've created my use to avoid the issue :

```
$adminValues = [
    'username'         => $username,
    'firstname'        => $firstname,
    'lastname'         => $lastname,
    'email'            => $email,
    'password'         => $password,
    'interface_locale' => 'fr_FR',
    'is_active'        => 1,
];

try {
        $admin = $this->userFactory->create();
        $newResetPasswordLinkToken = $this->customerHelper->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
        $admin->setData($adminValues)
              ->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken)
              ->setRoleId(1)
              ->save();
        $this->notificatorInterface->sendForgotPassword($admin);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->debug($e->getTraceAsString());
}
```

The method `changeResetPasswordLinkToken()` will set user `rp_token` data, which is mandatory when using your link from the forgot password email (template `password_reset_confirmation.html`).

This is called in `Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\ResetPassword.php` in `_validateResetPasswordLinkToken();` where user `rp_token` data that you just set is compared to the one given by the email link.

I didn't see other answers to this issue, hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem.  If you check the class AccountManagement (located: vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php).

You will find this was changed in 2.2.6.  In my case an extension had copied the entire class to there extension which is now out of date and because of this throws an exception.  Chances are that bitnami have done the same and they need to update there extension to be 2.2.6 compliant.