# Reset Password Problem : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, change-password

I have an error regarding `Forgot Password`. When I got an email to Reset Password I have got

> Your password reset link has expired.

I tried to `die` exception

```
Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword::execute()
```

and got this error :

```
Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException: Invalid value of "0" provided for the customerId field. in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:933 Stack trace: #0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(490): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->validateResetPasswordToken(0, '') #1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php(63): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->validateResetPasswordLinkToken(0, '') #2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword->execute() #3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin') #6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...') #9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck') #12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Array, 'customer_accoun...') #15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php(60): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...') #18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #20 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...') #21 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #23 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #24 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePassword\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #27 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...') #28 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #30 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install') #31 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #33 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...') #34 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #36 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...') #37 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #39 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #40 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #42 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#43 {main}
```

What is this error, and how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: any help ??????

Comment: please follow this link for the patch. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212210/your-password-reset-link-has-expired-magento-2

Comment: Note: This was fixed in 2.2.6, so if you get this error now, it's something else...

Comment: @Jsparo30 , Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?