# Remove shipping method auto apply from cart in magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shopping-cart

I have installed Webshop matrix rate extension and its working fine.

Whenever i add product to the cart, Automatically it takes the first shipping method and applies the shipping price for the cart total.

So is it possible to remove shipping method section from the cart page ?

Comment: Is multiple shipping methods are shown on cart page or only single shipping method is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

> app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Create reference blok `<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">` and use `componentDisabled` to disable component.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

And i think you can also use `remove block` methode to remove block like `<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true" />` add this code in `checkout_cart_index` file.

I hope it helps!

Comment: hi @Chirag patel, yes it worked..

Comment: Good happy to help :)

Comment: can you help on this pls, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212210/your-password-reset-link-has-expired-magento-2

Comment: Sorry @jafarpinjar i am not familiar with  Magento REST API.
But let me try if i found something.

Comment: okay fine, @Chirag, shipping not removed exactly, it loads after some time

Comment: Have you clear cache.

Comment: yes, cleared cache and checked

Comment: Any error getting in log file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91199/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-chirag-patel).

Comment: no error, still the first option is auto-selecting when cart page is loaded

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/313671/57334 anyone help me thanks